# How can I set a template variable reference on the first item of a list in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I would like to set a template variable reference on the first item of a list. Here is my code (which doesn't work) :

```
<li *ngFor="let favorite of favorites; let first= first">
    <template [ngIf]="first" #firstitem>
        {{ favorite.name }}
    </template>
    <template [ngIf]="!first">
        {{ favorite.name }}
    </template>
</li>
```

If I remove the `ngFor` here is what I would like to do :

```
<ul>
    <li #firstitem>
      some content
    </li> 
    <li>
      other content
    </li> 
</ul
```

Does someone have any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to conditionally add or not add a template variable.

What you can do is to use

```
@ViewChilderen('firstitem') items:QueryList<ElementRef>;

firstItem:ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  var items = this.items.toArray();
  if(items.length) {
    this.firstItem = items[0];
  }
}
```

and then you can use `firstItem` for bindings in the template.